# javascript clearInterval not working immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am animating a div using jquery animate plus using a setInterval.

However when I clearInterval, the animation should stop. But it is stopping after some time. The effect is not immediate.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var blinkTime;

  $('#one').click(function(){
   blinkTime = setInterval(function(){
      $('#a').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
      $('#a').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000); 
   }, 1000);

  });



  $('#two').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
   window.clearInterval(blinkTime);

  });
});
```

please have a look at this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bavayo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interval just kicks off a one second animation, so clearing the interval will prevent it from starting the next one. It won't however stop the animation. You can do that with `$("#a").stop();`. Check out [the documentation for jQuery's .stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: Awesome. Never knew about stop(). Thanks

Comment: @Ajey: Never knew about `.stop()`? You're using it in your jsBin demo.

Comment: @Ajey: Huh??? It was in the demo before this answer was posted. I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 3):

Your demo is different from your code in the question.

In the question you have an interval of `1000`, but animations totaling `2000`. As such, you likely have a queue of animate calls built up.

I would suggest not trying to coordinate jQuery animations with your own timers. Instead use a callback to restart the animation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using something like $('#a').stop(true,true).animate...

Check jquery stop function.